# DynamoDB update with composite primary key with node sdk

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I'm looking to use the update function part of the document client in the dynamoDB javascript SDK. My dynamoDB table has a primary partition key of "PK" (String) and a primary sort key "SK" (String). My understanding is this means my items need to be identified with their composite primary key which is some combination of "PK" and "SK"

I am using a single table design so an example item would look like

PK "CONTEST#2021"

SK: "POST#5673"

author: "USER#2759"

text: "Lorem ipsum"

commentNumber: 9

The logic of my code looks like this

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.addComment = async (event, context, callback) => {

const params = {
    TableName: 'App', 
    Key: {
        "PK": event.PK,
        "SK": event.SK
    },       
    UpdateExpression: 'set commentNumber = :number',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':number': event.updatedCommentCount
    }
}

try {
    var res = await dynamo.update(params).promise()
    // handleSuccess(res)
} catch(err) {
    // handleFail(err)
}

return 'success'

};
```

When I try the code above, i get an error saying `the provided key element does not match the schema`

I know there's something wrong with the `Key` key in my params, but the documentation isn't helping. It suggests it's possible to update with a composite key and seems to suggest that the value for `Key` can be an object with two keys, but this isn't working. How can I update my params to use the update function?

Comment: At this point I would double check `event.PK` and `event.SK` are strings. I've also heard of instances where partition key and/or sort key were misconfigured, names were not matching etc. You may want to double-check on overview tab of your DynamoDB table in AWS console.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the same issue.

Comment: unfortunately not. I ended up getting around this just by replacing the row entirely

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to use `#` in front of attribute names like so: `...UpdateExpression: 'set #commentNumber = :number',...`

Comment: i retried with 

        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#commentNumber' : 'commentNumber'
        },
        UpdateExpression: 'set #commentNumber = :number'

and got the same result

Comment: Could you please add a sample element from your table, including partition and sort keys, to the original post? Also what is the data type for the partition and sort keys?

Comment: good idea, just added an example item. both PK and SK require strings, which I can confirm through console.logs are being passed through.

if you're asking about the datatype for my partition and sort keys, does that mean that the structure of "Key" in my params look like it should work and the problem might be something else?

Answer (score 0):

So I had a similar issue and came across this thread. What ended up working for me is setting the Key attribute by first creating a key object and then assigning it to the update_parameter.

```
var update_params = {
  TableName: 'App',
};

let key = {};
key.PK = event.PK;
key.SK = event.SK;

update_params.Key = key;

update_params.UpdateExpression = UpdateExpression;
update_params.ExpressionAttributeValues = ExpressionAttributeValues;
```